# Trying to retrieve an error from addding a computer to AD using Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell-v3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve an error from adding a already there computer in Active Directory. Here's the script that I'm using to add my machine in my domain.

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "myDomain" -OUPath "ou=Postes de travail,ou=Ordinateurs,ou=TRB,DC=,dc=,dc=,dc=" -credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myUser", (ConvertTo-SecureString "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force))) -PassThru -ErrorVariable $test -OutVariable $test1
```

In my Powershell ISE I see the error saying that my machine already exist but I'm trying to trap that so I can ask the user if he wants to remove it and then try to re-add the computer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it with the [`-ErrorAction`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/11/03/erroraction-and-errorvariable.aspx) parameter:

```
Add-Computer ... -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable computerError
```

The ErrorVariable is an array, so the resulting error will be stored in:

```
$computerError[0]
```

To use the same variable over and over again, use a `+` in front of the var name:

```
Add-Computer -ErrorVariable +manyErrors
```

And the last error will always be:

```
$manyErrors[$manyerrors.count - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you it worked great. Now I get the complete error in my variable. How can I get the error number instead on the error phrase ?

Comment: If the exception has a native Win32 error code you should be able to access it at `$manyErrors[$manyerrors.count - 1].Exception.InnerException.NativeErrorCode`

Comment: It doesn't have a native Win32 error but I managed to use .CategoryInfo.Category.value__ an it returns 7 so I guess I'm good. Unless you tell me otherwise.